# What's the opposite of \b character, i.e. a kind of non-erasing space?

Tags: python, string, character, ascii, tty

The `\b` control character, as I understand it, is not supposed to erase the previous character (this would be `\b` + a del character as well), so something like this works:

```
>>> print 'pototo\b\b\ba'
potato
```

Is there a character for moving forwards, like a non-overwriting space?   Expected usage would be something like (I've called this character `\x`):

```
>>> print 'pototo\r\x\x\xa'
potato
```

Obviously on a typewriter a normal space would do this just fine.  But on a terminal a space erases the letter underneath.

My use case is a pexpect matching kind of scenario where I want to *retrospectively* go back and decorate certain parts of the output of a character stream with colours, and I'm wondering whether keeping a cache of the whole current line in memory will be necessary or not.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any way to move forwards in [python's "escape sequence tokens"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-escapeseq)...

Comment: I don't believe there is such a character, at least an exhaustive search didn't reveal any. However, under linux you should be able to explicitly set the cursor position using the [curses module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can rely on [ANSI escape code sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in your terminal (*), you can use the Cursor Forward (CUF) sequence "CSI *n* C", like this:

```
print "Pototo\b\b\ba\x1b[2Ces"
```

and get:

```
Potatoes
```

CSI is `\x1b[`, and is used to start ANSI escape code sequences. `2` is the number of characters to move to the right, and `C` is the command to move rightwards.

---

(*) A good approximation is that you can rely on ANSI codes unless you need to support Windows.

Comment: another use case: `print 'Hello Tim\b\b\bw\x1b[2C, great question'` :)

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write the characters:

```
>>> print 'pototo\rpota'
potato
```

If you do not want to re-write them , than you ought to use a library like [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) to manually set the cursor position.

Comment: The problem with this is then you can't append anything to the end of the word (without overwriting).

Comment: @hayden My point is that command line was not written to allow these complex situations. You can completely rewrite a single line(as my answer points out) but trying to do anything else you will have not portable code. I'd advise you to use `curses` or an other library for terminal manipulation if you want to do such things.

Comment: Sorry I did not properly read the second part of your answer.